# How to set up a problem involving independent probabilities.

Tags: probability

A heavy-duty vehicle has four sets of tyres, two on the left and two on the right, each set comprising two tyres. The vehicle will continue to operate if all sets have at most one punctured tyre. If each of the 8 tyres develops a puncture independently with probability $p$, what is the probability that vehicle continues to operate?

I'm having trouble setting up this problem.

I usually show what I've done with the problem so far, but this time my brain is fried. I want to let $A$ be a ruptured tyre and $B$ be a healthy tyre, and then count the number of combinations of $AA$, $AB$ and $BA$ etc. but then there's that probability $p$ that I don't know how to deal with. So then I think, well if they're independent then I know that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ but I don't know what to do with that apart from realise that it equals $p(1-p)$. I am very, very lost.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be amazing. I'm sorry if this question is trivial. I'm just not getting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Focus on one pair of tires.  What is the probability that it functions (i.e. not both tires in the pair get punctured).  This probability should be the same for each of the four pairs of tires.  Then what is the probability that all four pairs of tires remain functional?

Comment: So would that be $1-(1-p)^{2}$ for each pair of tyres, or am I still lost?

Comment: If not, my final answer would be $(p^{2}+2p)^{4}$.

Comment: I feel like that's wrong. I will keep plugging away. Thank you and @Alex for your responses.

Comment: What is the probability of failure (puncture) for both tires in a pair?  Then the probability that one given pair continues to function would be the complementary probability ($1-P(\text{both fail})$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 'at most one' means either 0 or 1. What's the probability that you have this number of punctures?